# Como fazer uma box e um href nessa box

Tags: html, css

Bom eu queria criar uma box onde quando clicada aparece um hoover e ela tenha um link:
ex:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

com hoover:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como está a minha até o momento :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo html:

```
 <section id="promo">
       <?php
                $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtohome");
                $consulta -> execute();

                $linhas = $consulta -> rowCount();

                foreach($consulta as $mostra):
            ?>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="skin"src="images/<?= $mostra['produto_img']?>" alt="Nome da Empresa: <?= $mostra['produto_nome']?>" title="Nome da Empresa: <?= $mostra['produto_nome']?>">
              <h1 class="color-white text-center font-text-light-med font-weight-heavy bgcolor-black"><?= $mostra['produto_nome']?></h1>
              <p class="bgcolor-gray text-center color-dark-full font-text-light-med">Por: R$ <?= number_format($mostra['produto_preco'], 2,',','.')?></p>
              <button class="bgcolor-red text-center btn"><a href="comprar.php?prod=<?= $mostra['produto_id']?>">Comprar</a></button>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </section>
```

css:

```
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}
.skin {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}
.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara eu não sei se é exatamente isso que vc precisa, mas coloquei alguns atributos no card para fazer a "borda" vermelha com um `outline`. E a conteúdo interno eu criei uma `div` que fica oculta e no `:hover` no card esse conteúdo aparece.

Veja como ficou no exemplo.

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card:hover {
box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  outline: 4px solid red;
}
.skin {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}
.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.card .info {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
.card:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="promo">

    <div class="card">
      <img class="skin"src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="Nome da Empresa: 
      <?= $mostra['produto_nome']?>" title="Nome da Empresa: <?= $mostra['produto_nome']?>">
      <div class="info">
        <span>conteúdo</span>
      </div>
      <h1 class="color-white text-center font-text-light-med font-weight-heavy bgcolor-black"><?= $mostra['produto_nome']?></h1>
      <p class="bgcolor-gray text-center color-dark-full font-text-light-med">Por: R$ <?= number_format($mostra['produto_preco'], 2,',','.')?></p>
      <button class="bgcolor-red text-center btn"><a href="comprar.php?prod=<?= $mostra['produto_id']?>">Comprar</a></button>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</section>
```

Comment: era exatamente isso man vlw mesmo

Comment: @GabrielCosta que bom que ajudou, boa sorte ai!

Comment: opa mano eu vou criar uma nova pergunta sobre por um contador em cima dessa imagem eu tou tentando por, mas n tou conseguindo e te mando o link vc poderia me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: @GabrielCosta eu não manjo muito de JS, na verdade quase nada, mas o que vc precisar de ajuda com o layout eu te ajudo sim

Comment: vlw eu vou dar uma procurada melhor, @hugocsl e sobre esse codigo eu tentei por e ficou exatamente desse jeito http://prntscr.com/ky5tm3, vc chamou  jquery?

Comment: Não aparece o hoover quando clica  nem a borda.

Comment: @GabrielCosta esse CSS que fíz funciona apenas no :Hover, ou seja quando o usuário passa o mouse sobre o card. Se vc quiser trocar a classe quando ele clica com o mouse, ai só com jquery ou JS... É isso mesmo que vc quer, que só quando o cara clicar no card aparece as informações?

Comment: estava certo, mas tipo o hoover quando passa o mouse não está indo o hoover e eu utilizei o mesmo codigo.

Comment: ta ficando estático e sem hoover como nessa print  ; prntscr.com/ky5tm3

Comment: Cara se aqui funciona eh para funcionar no seu código tb. Vc esta usando algum outro CSS? Tenta colocar esse código em outro html pra ver se funciona. Se funcionar, eh pq tem algum CSS na sua pagina atual que esta interferindo nesse CSS novo. Retire os css desnecessários etc... Vc esta usando bootstrap?

Comment: vou testar, não estou usando bootstrap não.